# Django - Migrate new field with value from old field

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a field `pub_date`. I want to add a new field `created_date`, which should take the value from `pub_date`.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean for the old data, or for new data as well?

Comment: The old data (`pub_date`) should be copied to the new data (`created_date`). They are the same field type (both `DateTimeField`)